# How to search a message on Firefox web console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log

The Firefox web console (showing Javascript console.log messages) has a search box allowing to 'filter' messages. This is useful to find if a certain message 'foo' has been shown on console, but filtering hides all the other messages on console, so it is not possible to see exactly **when** 'foo' has been logged.

I would want to 'search' among console messages in order to debug js scripts, to see when a message has been logged and check previous and following messages.

I've searched a lot, but it seems like this feature is not there. There is a way to achieve this result with the native console or some plugin console having this feature?

Comment: There is no feature available that allows you to filter for a message and show the last x messages not fitting the criteria. You could, however, enable the timestamp for log messages (top right corner, the settings icon, enable timestamp). Filter your messages, look up the timestamp and remove the filter. I'd suggest using the debugger though.

Comment: Maybe you can add the `debug` keyword after the `console.log` you want to check and the script will stop there.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Yes, I was not searching for such a feature, but more something like a normal 'search on page' like any browser offers, highlighting the term searched in the whole log to be able to find what I need, in place. The timestamp solution fits! If you convert it in an answer I will accept it. I'm definitively think is the only way to reach such a goal.

Comment: @SashaGrievus I added my comment as an answer :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested, I'll convert my comment to an answer, but leave the comment as is (so people will not be confused).

There is no feature available that allows you to filter for a message and show the last x messages not fitting the criteria. You could, however, enable the timestamp for log messages (top right corner, the settings icon, enable timestamp). Filter your messages, look up the timestamp and remove the filter. I'd suggest using the debugger though.